# RoR - Devise Confirmable email error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, devise, devise-confirmable

I'm using Ruby on Rails 3 with Devise and sending confirmation emails.  The emails work correctly (as far as sending) but when I click on the Confirm my account link, it generates an error.
Can anyone shed some light, or at least point me in the right direction on what this is/how to fix this?

This is the error I see in the logs:

```
Started GET "/users/confirmation?confirmation_token=qKvZWHgj6ncYAyuQq3e1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2012-08-15 20:57:11 +0300
Processing by ConfirmationsController#show as HTML
  Parameters: {"confirmation_token"=>"qKvZWHgj6ncYAyuQq3e1"}
  User Load (9.0ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."confirmation_token" = 'qKvZWHgj6ncYAyuQq3e1' LIMIT 1
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 35920ms

NoMethodError (undefined method `only_if_unconfirmed' for #):
  app/controllers/confirmations_controller.rb:58:in `with_unconfirmed_confirmable'
  app/controllers/confirmations_controller.rb:40:in `show'


  Rendered C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.5/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_trace.erb (8.0ms)
  Rendered C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.5/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_request_and_response.erb (3.0ms)
  Rendered C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.5/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/diagnostics.erb within rescues/layout (4479.3ms)
```

I verified that the token in the url is an exact match for this user in the db.

Comment: Have you customized devise in any way? or overridden any controllers?

Comment: Yes.  I know it was something I did but I'm wondering in which direction to look.  Worse case, I can remove it and re-install it.

Answer (score 0):

Probably you have a really recent version of devise, and it changed the way the confirmation token is handled, so if you generate the views with devise like so:

```
rails g devise:views
```

Then under the **app/views/devise/mailer/confirmation_instructions.html.erb** file you have  something like:

```
....
<%= link_to 'Confirm my account', confirmation_url(@resource, :confirmation_token => @resource.confirmation_token) %>
....
```

You should change that for:

```
<%= link_to 'Confirm my account', confirmation_url(@resource, :confirmation_token => @token) %>
```

As you can see they use an instance variable called `@token` instead of `@resource.confirmation_token`

That should do the trick!